# Emberjs Model updates only partially

Tags: ember.js

I have a table component, which is feed with a model.
If updated data comes from the server, i push the payload into the store, which updates the model, and the table should re-render.

The problem: Despite that all record is updated (see different **exchange** values) only those will be re-rendered, where the **iso** value is different too. I discovered there is a connection between the **sortProperties** array and the re-rendered rows. If I change **sortProperties** to

```
sortProperties: ['name'],
```

then all those rows will be re-rendered, where the record's name has been updated.

The expected behavior will be, if all three row would be re-rendered, since all three record's **exchange** property is changed.

### http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jofulufina/16/edit

some explanation:
`sortPropertiesWithOrders` generates a string based on `asc` and `sortProperties` arrays. The string is used in `multiSort`, which is a computed.sort property, and it multisorting the content (the model) of the table.

**UPDATE**

I have found a solution to the problem, but it is not flexible at all:
`sortPropertiesWithOrders` should observe each element's exchange property in content. Since it is a component, the content's property is unpredictable, and i can't hard code it like in this example.
The working, but not optimal JsBin:

### http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bawatonela/1/edit

**(HOPEFULLY) LAST UPDATE**
Now I define `sortPropertiesWithOrders` in the table component's init. This way I can build dynamically the string of the dependent keys to it. Someone may find helpful the code:

```
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    var columns = this.get('columns');
    var i=0;
    var cps = [];
    for(i=0; i < columns.length; i++ ){
        if (columns[i].property)
          cps.push(columns[i].property);
    }
    var str = 'content.@each.{' + cps.join(',') + '}';


    Ember.defineProperty(this, 'sortPropertiesWithOrders',   Ember.computed(str, 'sortProperties', 'asc', function(){
      var ret = Ember.A();
      var asc = this.get('asc');
      this.get('sortProperties').forEach(function(property, i){

        var tmp = asc[i] ? property : property + ':desc';
        ret.push(tmp);
      });

      return ret;
    }));
  },
```

And the working JsBin:

### http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bawatonela/3/edit?js,output

Idea is shamelessly stolen from @intuitivepixel https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1128#issuecomment-93613364